# php não exibe acentuação com utf-8

Tags: php, sql-server, bootstrap-3

Estou trabalhando com PHP 5.6 e SQL Server.
Estou trabalhando com bootstrap e o banco de dados está Latin1_General_CI_AS.
Meu HTML está conforme abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Print em anexo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Latin1_General_CI_AS não é encoding, é collation. Collation não interfere na saída, mas provavelmente se o collation é esse, a tabela está em Latin1 e como você está colocando UTF8 na página, então não vai funcionar mesmo. Ou acerta o encoding, ou a página. Veja nas respostas do link indicado acima as possibilidades para deixar seu sistema em ordem. Como último recurso, se não puder consertar o DB ou a definição da página, use a função `utf8_encode()` para converter os dados de saída.

Comment: Resolvido.
<?= utf8_encode( $os['NomeSetor']); ?>
Só preciso que vc coloque como resposta para que eu possa marcar a sua resposta.

Comment: Como já marquei como duplicata, tá resolvido, pq quem localizar pela sua pergunta vai achar a outra, que já explica bem. O importante é vc ter solucionado. Se eu respondesse aqui, ia ficar dividido, atrapalhando os próximos visitantes. As duplicatas servem como uma maneira de procurar por palavras diferentes, e chegar nos mesmos resultados.